# Trying to install Homestead Laravel

Tags: laravel, sublimetext3, homestead

I'm at the 5:35 mark of this Youtube tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bC8OjU5ZlJQ).  When he opens `Homestead.yaml` in Sublime Text 3, under Folders in the left margin it says the parent folder is .homestead and there are three files within the folder including `Homestead.yaml`.  When I go to my Homestead.yaml file, I have to go to ~/www/Homestead/src/stubs/Homestead.yaml.  When I open the file that way, under Folders in the left margin of Sublime Text it doesn't show .homestead as the open Folder.  Is that a problem?  Also it lists `LocalizedVagrantfile` with `after.sh`, `aliases` and `Homestead.yaml`.  This seems different than what the guy shows in the video.  Is this a problem?

I see that the .homestead file is within my Home directory:

```
Josephs-MBP:~ code$ cd .homestead
Josephs-MBP:.homestead code$ ls
Homestead.yaml  after.sh    aliases
```

Why don't I see the `.homestead` folder in my Home directory?

Sorry if these are stupid questions.  Just trying to get this on my computer so I can get to some actual coding.  THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0):

Unix-based environments (Macs, Linux) hide files/folders that begin with `.` from the GUI and from `ls`.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidden_file_and_hidden_directory#Unix_and_Unix-like_environments

Comment: So then, how do I get to `Homestead.yaml` through `.homestead` using my text editor?

Comment: @jrath5 https://www.google.com/search?q=show+hidden+files+osx or `nano .homestead/Homestead.yaml` in your Termianl.